# d3.js/Typescript: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function line(da…"

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and I'm trying to re-write https://medium.com/@lambrospd/5-simple-rules-to-data-visualization-with-vue-js-and-d3-js-f6b2bd6a1d40 to vue3 + typescript

Below please find my code

```
<template>
  <svg
    class="line-chart"
    :viewBox="viewBox"
  >
    <g transform="translate(0, 10)">
      <path
        class="line-chart__line"
        :d="path(data)"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
 </template>


<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent,computed, toRef } from 'vue';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
export default defineComponent({
  name: "StandardMetric",
  props: {
    data: {
      required: true,
      type: Array,
    },
    width: {
      default: 500,
      type: Number,
    },
    height: {
      default: 270,
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  setup(props){
        const padding = 60;

        const data = [99, 71, 78, 25, 36, 92];

       const rangeY = computed(() => {
        const defaultHeight: number =props.height?props.height:270;
        const height: number = defaultHeight - padding;
        return [0, height];
      });
      
      const rangeX = computed(() => {
        const defaultWidth: number =props.width?props.width:500;
        const width: number = defaultWidth - padding;
        return [0, width];
      });

      
      const path =(linedata: number[])=> {

    
      const maxIndex: number = linedata.length-1;
  
      let maxValue = d3.max(linedata);
      maxValue = maxValue?maxValue:0
      const x = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeX.value).domain([0, maxIndex]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeY.value).domain([0, maxValue]);

      d3.axisLeft(x);
      d3.axisTop(y);

      // return d3.line<ChartData>()
      //    .x((d:ChartData, i) => x(i))
      //   // .x(d=>x(d))
      //   .y((d:ChartData) => y(d.p));
       return d3.line<number>()
              .x((d, i)=>x(i))
              .y(d=>y(d))
     }

     const line = computed(()=> {
       return path(data)
     })

     const viewBox = computed(() =>{
      return `0 0 ${props.width} ${props.height}`;
    })

     return {
       line,
       viewBox,
       path,
       data
     }


  }
}
)
</script>
```

When I loaded the page, I got below error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function line(da…".
patchAttr @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:194
patchProp @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:386
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3905
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3868
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3788
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3975
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3896
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3868
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3788
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3975
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3896
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3868
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3788
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3975
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4141
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3784
componentEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4298
reactiveEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:42
effect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:17
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4263
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4222
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4182
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3791
patchBlockChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4091
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4152
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3784
patchBlockChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4091
patchElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4055
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3871
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3788
componentEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4368
reactiveEffect @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:42
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:154
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:384
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:286
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:280
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:183
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:189
scheduler @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:851
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:183
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:189
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:761
handleClick @ Home.vue:114
onClick @ Home.vue:35
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:163
emit @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:642
(anonymous) @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6689
handleClick @ index.esm.js:1
createBlock.onClick.t.<computed>.t.<computed> @ index.esm.js:1
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:163
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:333
Show 4 more frames
```

I have below in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tools-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^6.3.0",
    "d3": "^6.6.2",
    "element-plus": "^1.0.2-beta.36",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.5",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.2.1",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.8.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "vite": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.0.15"
  }
}
```

I believe it's something wrong with my path function but I have no clue what's the problem.
Can you please help?
Thanks

Comment: print to console the result of  d3.line<number> before you return it and see if it's a valid path (starts with  M)

Answer (score 0):

I got it - the keys are:

1. Path function needs to return the "function of how to determine the path"
2. Line function needs to be computed & needs to take a function from path function then use the data
   Below is the working version

```
<template>
  <svg
    class="line-chart"
    :viewBox="viewBox"
  >
    <g transform="translate(0, 10)">
      <path
        class="line-chart__line"
        :d="line"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
 </template>


<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent,computed, toRef } from 'vue';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
export default defineComponent({
  name: "StandardMetric",
  props: {
    data: {
      required: true,
      type: Array,
    },
    width: {
      default: 500,
      type: Number,
    },
    height: {
      default: 270,
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  setup(props){
        const padding = 60;

        const data = [99, 71, 78, 25, 36, 92];

       const rangeY = computed(() => {
        const defaultHeight: number =props.height?props.height:270;
        const height: number = defaultHeight - padding;
        return [0, height];
      });
      
      const rangeX = computed(() => {
        const defaultWidth: number =props.width?props.width:500;
        const width: number = defaultWidth - padding;
        return [0, width];
      });

      
      const path =()=> {

    
      const maxIndex: number = data.length-1;
  
      let maxValue = d3.max(data);
      maxValue = maxValue?maxValue:0
      const x = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeX.value).domain([0, maxIndex]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range(rangeY.value).domain([0, maxValue]);

      d3.axisLeft(x);
      d3.axisTop(y);

      return d3.line<number>()
              .x((d, i)=>x(i))
              .y(d=>y(d))
     }

     const line = computed(()=> {
       const pathFunc = path()
       return pathFunc(data)
     })

     const viewBox = computed(() =>{
      return `0 0 ${props.width} ${props.height}`;
    })

     return {
       line,
       viewBox,
  
     }


  }
}
)
</script>
```

Hope it will help someone in the future